# Insert TODOs and SCHEDULE items in calendar view

Tags: org-capture, calendar

We can do this with 'k' in agenda. How to insert / capture tasks at Calendar in Emacs? It would be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: What does "insert / capture tasks at Calendar in Emacs" mean to you?  Can you provide an example?  Does that mean you want colored squares to appear on the calendar for certain TODOs and SCHEDULE; or does it mean that you want to simply have the default date for new items (when calling `M-x org-capture`) be the date at point when you are viewing the `*Calendar*` buffer; or does it mean something else?

Comment: I just want to be able to create from a specific date in the Calendar (being the cursor on that date) a task (scheduled, non-scheduled, deadline, etc.). Exactly having the date of such task as the date where the cursor is on the calendar.